Exceeding a relay's safety AC rating
I was wondering if it would be a safety hazard to exceed a relay's AC rating of 125VAC with 230VAC? Will it work? Here's the data sheet. I'm using the 5V variant.
Image source: Mantech Electronics - N4100 relay datasheet


I'm curious whether the 220VAC rating is a type rating (thus including up to 265V plus transients) or an actual maximum. Possibly these parameters are defined in the IEC standards, but this parameter doesn't reference one and I wonder if you'd simply have to ask the manufacturer. Which is a good first-line target for questions like this anyway.

The section of the part identifier labeled "5" in the datasheet specifies the contact rating at 125 VAC, 30 VDC and what appears to be 14 VDC, although there is a following 30 VDC which is likely a mistake.
Suppose you have chosen the 5 amp version. Then the contacts will work with 5 amps at 125 VAC. The maximum switching voltage is 220 VAC, but there is no guarantee that it is safe to switch 5 amps at that voltage. There is even less reason to believe that there is any safe amount of current when switching more than the maximum rated switching voltage, i.e. 230 VAC instead of 220 VAC.
Will it work at 230 VAC? It might (and it is more likely to if your maximum current is well below the rating). But the risk is entirely on you. A well designed application would either use only 125 VAC on this relay, or would use a higher rated relay.

Interesting. I have never seen a relay fail before. Will it blow up?

@ZiphoLunika Unlikely. But it may fail earlier than when used normally. Contacts may weld together or fail to make proper connection. And poor connection between contacts may overheat the contacts ot melt plastic.

@ZiphoLunika To be fair, how many relays have you seen, and operating over how many switching cycles? Relays fail, even when operating inside normal conditions - they've got moving parts - it's just a question of when, not if. (When might be very far in the future, of course)

The datasheet shows:

The Max Switching Voltage is 220VAC, which is less than 230VAC.
The UL&CUR Safety Approval is for 3A  5A/125VAC.

Given the above I would say this relay is not designed to be safely used for 230VAC.
Operating a device outside of the manufacturers published datasheet parameters means:

It isn't guaranteed to work.
Any investigation after a safety failure will likely question why a higher rated relay wasn't selected.


It also means you don't know whether each device will perform the in same way and to the same level outside the limitations, either. You might test a couple and they seem to work well, and suddenly the next batch of devices can crap out in those conditions.

There are two ratings on the datasheet- 220VAC/5A  and 5A/125VAC.
My interpretation is that the first one is what the manufacturer claims is okay, the second is what it has been tested to be (relatively) safe at by a third part testing lab.
Aside from the 230VAC vs. 220VAC discrepancy, the relay is "almost" good enough by the manufacturer's estimation. It either failed UL testing or they did not pay to have it tested (perhaps feeling it might fail).
Is it a safety hazard if you used it to switch 230VAC resistive? Maybe. There's no way to really know. It's perhaps more likely that it just won't perform very well and might stick 'on' or do something else undesirable.
There could be technical and non-technical consequences as a result of violating the limits which will be clearly printed on the side of the component.

It sure isn't smart -
The voltage rating is there due to the internal construction of the relay contacts. More voltage requires more physical space to safely prevent arcing. Arcing breaks down the contact material.
As said before, might work for a little while, but certainly not too long
